# Problems with pushback into vector object C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I am having problems iterating though a vector of objects.

In this member function I am attempting to step through each element of the array. 
However, the if statement appears to be skipped despite the conditions being met.
When I tested listAccounts.size() at the start of the function, it prints 0.

```
void Account::change_balance(string name, int balance) {

    for(auto& account : listAccounts) {
        if(account.account_name == name) {
            account.account_balance += balance;
            cout << account.account_balance;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "account does not exist""\n";
}
```

So must this be a problem with how I pushback into the vector listAccounts?
This is the function where I pushback into the vector:

```
void Account::init_account(string name, char type) {

        Account account;

        if (type == 'y') {              
            account.account_type = 1;
        } else if (type == 'n') {
            account.account_type = 0;
        }

        account.account_name = name;
        account.account_balance = 0;

        listAccounts.push_back(account);
        cout << listAccounts.size() << "\n";
        }
```

This same function is called every time the user enters 'create' in main.
and the change_balance function is called every time the user enters 'transaction' in main.

Here is the class definition:

```
class Account {
    public:
        string account_name;
        bool account_type;      
        int account_balance;
        static vector<Account> listAccounts;


        //member function declaration
        void init_account(string name, char type);
        void change_balance(string name, int balance);
        void remove_account(string name);

};
vector<Account> Account::listAccounts;
```

The program should create an account with name & type, and pushback into listAccounts, as well as update the balance of the vector element with account_name = name in listAccounts.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Account {
    public:
        string account_name;
        bool account_type;      
        int account_balance;
        static vector<Account> listAccounts;


        //member function declaration
        void init_account(string name, char type);
        void change_balance(string name, int balance);
        void remove_account(string name);

};
vector<Account> Account::listAccounts;

//member functions definitions
void Account::init_account(string name, char type) {

    Account account;

    cout << listAccounts.size();    //test to see size before pushback

    if (type == 'y') {              
        account.account_type = 1;
    } else if (type == 'n') {
        account.account_type = 0;
    }

    account.account_name = name;
    account.account_balance = 0;

    listAccounts.push_back(account);
    cout << "\n" << listAccounts.size() << "\n";    //test to see size
    }

void Account::change_balance(string name, int balance) {

    cout << listAccounts.size() << " accounts to check\n";
    for(auto& account : listAccounts) {
        cout << "Testing " << account.account_name << "\n";
        if(account.account_name == name) {
            account.account_balance += balance;
            cout << account.account_balance;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "account does not exist""\n";
}


void Account::remove_account(string name) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(listAccounts.begin(), listAccounts.end(), 
             [&](const auto& s){ return s.account_name == name; });
    if(iter != listAccounts.end())
        listAccounts.erase(iter);  
}


//main
int main() {

    char action;
    string names;
    char types;
    int balance;
    Account account;

while(action != 'q') {
    int i = 0;
        cin >> action >> names;

        if (action == 'c') {
            cin >> types;
            account.init_account(names, types);
            i++;
        }

        else if (action == 't') {
            cin >> balance;
            account.change_balance(names, balance);  
        }

        else if (action == 'r'); {
            account.remove_account(names);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I clearly misread it :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 what am I missing?

Comment: @runrabbitrun I don't know, you haven't provided enough code. You should use a debugger and provide a mcve.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've edited it to include main(), but that's everything I have, the problem is with the vector which is included. I am trying to make it as readable as possible, i'm just a bit lost here. I've included everything I have apart from a function which I haven't written yet that removes elements from the vector.

Comment: @lcs nw, any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the input is into the program? (ie. I input `c` and then `john` and then `y`, or something like that...)

Comment: @callyalater exactly! the user inputs: c john y, which will call the init_account function with the intention of adding an element into the listAccounts vector, with name = john, and type = 1. Then, if the next input is: t john 100, for example, it calls change_balance with the intention of adding 100 john's account. However, when I test the listAccounts.size() at the begining of init_account it always prints 0, even if I have already created an account and pushback into listAccounts. It's as if the vector is cleared each time the function is called. Or any function for that matter.

Comment: I do not see an issue. See [here](https://ideone.com/s3FCpi).

Comment: @callyalater It's been killing me for ages, I cout listAccounts.size() before and after the pushback, and no matter how many accounts I have created it prints 1 then 0, every single time. I edited the question and put the whole program in the if that helps. And because of this none of the other functions work.

Comment: You need a while loop in your `main` function if you want to do more than one action per program run. `static` means only one copy of that variable per process, not one copy across program executions.

Comment: `else (action == 'r');` looks odd in a couple ways. You probably mean `else if` because `else` doesn't have any conditions. It's the result of `if`'s conditions failing. The second one is lose the semicolon. It ends the statement without attaching the body. Detached from the `else`, the  body will always run.

Comment: @user4581301 You figured it out. Funny how small syntax differences can affect the semantics so well. See [here](https://ideone.com/v5uXkO) for an example of it now.

Comment: @callyalater Thank you so much helping me out in a time of need, when it seemed like nobody else would. :)